# Delaying all incoming signals by 2 ms using VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl, delay, timing

I have two incoming signals that I want to test the coincidence between. But, I first want to delay all of the signals from one channel by the period at which the signals are being sent (2 ms) and compare the coincidence this way. So basically, I want to store the real-time information for 2 ms and then replay it as soon as it finishes collecting, and continue this process on and on. Is this feasible using an FPGA? I was thinking of using one of the following:

`outputA <= inputA after 2 ms;
outputA <= inertial inputA after 2 ms;
outputA <= transport inputA after 2 ms;`

but from what I understand, these are only used for simulation? What other method(s) would be better to accomplish such a task? Using a shift register, or something similar?

edit:

In my setup, I have two detectors (single photon counting modules) that convert photons of light into a digital signal (3.3V, about 50 ns pulse width). The signals are then being sent to an Altera DE2 board, where they are tested with AND gates for coincidence (note, the signals are being shortened from 50 ns to around 15 to 25 ns beforehand, with internal logic and no timing loss). The clock on this board runs at 50 MHz, which has a rising edge every 20 ns. **The laser sends a pulse every 2 ms.** The real counts and random noise counts from these detectors follow no clock, so they will not necessarily share a rising or falling edge exactly the 50 MHz clock. **Testing the coincidence is not the issue I'm having, what I need to do now is delay one of the signals by the period of the laser and test the coincidence then. Because the laser is so slow, it is impractical to delay the signal phisically (it would require around 1 km of optical fiber). So, I am trying to do this delay through the FPGA itself.** Now to rephrase my questions:

(1) Is it possible to maintain temporal accuracy (down to very few nanoseconds) when using a FIFO buffer **to delay one of the incoming signals**, or will sending the signals into the buffer lose that accuracy and only share rising/falling edges with my clock? (Does the buffer say that block of data is either entirely zero or entirely 1, depending on whether the signal was in a high or low state at the rising edge of the clock when it collects the data?)

(2) How would I begin to write code for such a buffer, is this something I can find a copy of online or would there be any "buffer wizards" that I can create using a VHDL program like Quartus II?

Comment: Do you have a 0.5 kHz clock, synchronized with your data, available?

Comment: what's your data rate or sampling rate?

Comment: How many bits in your shift register and what will the clock frequency be?

Comment: The delayed assignments in VHDL are purely a convenience provided in simulation. Remember VHDL is not a programming language for running instructions on a CPU but a descriptor language for designing digital logic circuits, like a circuit diagram does. So you need to imagine the digital logic circuit that can produce your delay operation, then write the VHDL to implement that circuit. Shift register running from a divider circuit that produces a shift enable seems sensible. Remember, don't make a clock by dividing down your logic clock - make an enable. Hope your experience makes this familiar.

Comment: I have a 50 MHz internal clock, and I am not sure about the bits in the shift register. Is that something that is limited by the hardware or something you program? And why do you not divide down a logic clock? I am relatively new to vhdl programming, so my experience is limited. I will look into creating an enable now.

Comment: My laser is sending a pulse every 2 ms, but the detector we use sends accidental signals in between that period as well.

Comment: "I want to test the coincidence" - how closely do you want to 'test' the coincidence, ie. what timing resolution do you want?

Comment: The incoming pulses are 50 ns wide, but are first internally shorted to 5-15 ns before I use logic AND gates to test for coincidence.

Comment: No,  a FIFO type delay will not offer time resolution finer than the clock interval.  Unless you can redefine your need it is likely to require fairly "exotic" techniques.  It sounds like you are in an academic or formal research setting, perhaps you have local instrumentation expertise you could discuss the entire experiment with?  There may well be a way to redesign it that makes the measurement a better fit for available technologies.

Comment: The existence of medium price gigasample scopes may offer a clue; your data seems not to actually be analog, but part of how these work is multiplexing the fast path, ie, you may be able to use a `deserializer` functional block to split a high speed 1-bit signal into a wider low speed signal and store it at more moderate speed in a many-bit-wide memory.  When you then examine the buffer at leisure, the time something happened is the word address times word width, plus the position of the bit in the word, all multiplied by the gigahertz or whatever sample interval.

Comment: Please look at my updated answer.

Comment: Do you want to delay a single, well defined event, or do you want to delay a bunch of noise somewhere within which your signal is hiding?  The deserializer idea can do either, but for a single event there may be simpler schemes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I want to delay a bunch of noise with the signal somewhere hidden inside. In your above comment, are you suggesting to use a faster external clock?

Comment: Look up SERDES.  You only need the deserializer, in essence if you split a fast stream into 8 parallel bits, you can build a gigasample FIFO out of memory running only an 8th as fast.  That's in concept, there will be practical details to work out as you don't have a standard communication interface as a source.  Or maybe 8 ns resolution is enough, and you can just use such memory directly.  Somewhere there's a combination of techniques and technology speeds that should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Any time value is not synthesizable by an FPGA, because an FPGA is not aware of the concept "time". Actually no electronic circuit is aware of our concept of time. In computers and such specific libraries were developed to ease programming with time.

However, synchronous electronics -like an FPGA- are usually clocked: driven by an oscillator. This oscillator has a certain intrinsic period: the clock frequency. You can use this frequency to measure a certain time period. I.e. an oscillator of 50 MHz will have oscillated 100000 times in 2 ms.

If you want to delay a signal, you will need to introduce memory into the system, which holds the information for a specific period. In this case 100000 clock cycles. You have a number of options there, one being a column of 100000 n-bit registers. However, using separate FPGA registers is quite inefficient.

Another solutions would be to use a feature of FPGA's that has been introduced not so long ago: it is possible to use the LUTs (look-up tables) as shift registers. This is much more efficient then using separate registers. However, in the case of 100000 clock cycles, this is still likely not so inefficient.

You are in fact making a FIFO (first-in first-out) buffer with a fixed delay. Seeing the delay is on the larger side, it is quite common to use a dual-port RAM block in this case: on the A-side you write the input data in an infinite loop and on the B-side you read this data with an address offset of 100000.

**after your edit:**

Ok, so it seems you are trying to determine the time between two pulses. That is something different -and much simpler- then determining the time-shift of data. This is actually done a lot in radar and lidar etc applications. The component that does that is a [Time-to-Digital converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-to-digital_converter). It simply determines the time between pulse 1 (start) and pulse 2 (stop), like a stopwatch does.

If you want to determine the time more accurately, i.e. with a sub-clock period interval, I suggest you look at the hybrid solution (i.e. the Nutt method). That one combines a simple counter with a vernier interpolator. A. Aloisio et al. have suggested a nice FPGA implementation in ["FPGA Implementation of High-Resolution Time-to-Digital Converter"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/4436263/4436264/04436379.pdf) (I hope you have access to IEEE).

Comment: a 50 MHz clock actually has 100,000 rising edges in 2 ms, will this large size still be feasible using a dual-port RAM block?

Comment: @Cody495 100k doesn't sound large for a RAM, does it? Of you really want to keep all data, you have no choice. But are you really sampling at 50 MHz? You should explain your problem better. For instance, what is "the signal"?

Comment: I have edited my original post, hopefully this explanation is more useful

Comment: To a very limited extent, "time value" actually is synthesizable, not from the HDL itself, but in terms of minimum and maximum constraints that may be placed for the later place & route stage.  The software has a model of the performance of the FPGA, and tries to find a path that will satisfy the need.  But this is not going to offer any obvious solution to the apparent problem of the question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton true, altough the FPGA still does not know the concept of "time" using that. The synthesis, place&route tool solves that for you. Furthermore, like you said: 2 ms is unachievable that way.

Comment: I still think I was a little unclear, I don't need help counting the coincidences (although the links you provided are interesting!), I need help delaying one of the signals by 2 ms. I made one more edit to clarify.

Comment: @Cody495 then just use the block RAM. Or have two data generators, generating the same data with a time offset.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius How would I go about writing the code to use the bock RAM then? Like I asked above, is this just a standard code I find online or use a wizard to create?

Comment: @Cody495 read the manufacturer's coding guidelines on how to instantiate a block RAM